Passing an action to a nested composable
I am developing a screen with a form to input passenger data using Jetpack Compose. The passenger data form function is integrated within the screen function. Upon pressing the "Save" button, the ViewModel verifies the data entered and updates the passenger state with errors if any are found. I wish to have the ViewModel signal the passenger form to scroll to the first erroneous field when errors are detected. However, I am unsure how to implement this action within the nested passenger form function.
I attempted to pass the needScroll SharedFlow from the ViewModel. In the ViewModel, I emit the Unit value to the SharedFlow after the passenger's state is updated. However, the issue arises when the value from the SharedFlow is collected by the PassengerForm before the new passenger state, containing errors, is received.
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val _passengerState = MutableStateFlow(PassengerState())
    val passengerState = _passengerState.asStateFlow()

    private val _needScroll = MutableSharedFlow<Unit>()
    val needScroll = _needScroll.asSharedFlow()

    fun onChangeField1(value: String) {
        _passengerState.update {
            it.copy(field1 = it.field1.copy(value = value, isError = false))
        }
    }

    fun onChangeField2(value: String) {
        _passengerState.update {
            it.copy(field2 = it.field2.copy(value = value, isError = false))
        }
    }

    fun onSave() {
        val cueState = _passengerState.value
        if (cueState.field1.value.isEmpty() || cueState.field2.value.isEmpty()) {
            _passengerState.update {
                it.copy(
                    field1 = it.field1.copy(isError = cueState.field1.value.isEmpty()),
                    field2 = it.field2.copy(isError = cueState.field2.value.isEmpty()),
                )
            }
            viewModelScope.launch {
                _needScroll.emit(Unit)
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun MyScreen(
    viewModel: MyViewModel,
) {
    val passengerState by viewModel.passengerState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
    val needScroll = remember { mutableStateOf(viewModel.needScroll) }

    MyPassengerForm(
        passengerState = passengerState,
        needScroll = needScroll,
        onChangeField1 = remember { { viewModel.onChangeField1(it) } },
        onChangeField2 = remember { { viewModel.onChangeField2(it) } },
        onSave = remember { { viewModel.onSave() } },
    )
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun MyPassengerForm(
    passengerState: PassengerState,
    needScroll: State<SharedFlow<Unit>>,
    onChangeField1: (String) -> Unit,
    onChangeField2: (String) -> Unit,
    onSave: () -> Unit,
) {
    val lifecycle = LocalLifecycleOwner.current.lifecycle
    val field1BringIntoView = remember { BringIntoViewRequester() }
    val field2BringIntoView = remember { BringIntoViewRequester() }
    LaunchedEffect(key1 = passengerState, key2 = needScroll) {
        lifecycle.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
            needScroll.value.collect {
                val bringIntoView = when {
                    passengerState.field1.isError -> field1BringIntoView
                    passengerState.field2.isError -> field2BringIntoView
                    else -> null
                }
                launch {
                    bringIntoView?.bringIntoView()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
    ) {
        TextField(
            modifier = Modifier.bringIntoViewRequester(field1BringIntoView),
            value = passengerState.field1.value,
            onValueChange = onChangeField1,
        )

        TextField(
            modifier = Modifier.bringIntoViewRequester(field2BringIntoView),
            value = passengerState.field2.value,
            onValueChange = onChangeField2,
        )

        Button(onClick = onSave) {
            Text(text = "Save")
        }
    }
}

data class PassengerState(
    val field1: FieldItem = FieldItem(),
    val field2: FieldItem = FieldItem(),
)

data class FieldItem(
    val value: String = "",
    val isError: Boolean = false,
)


A lot of your code doesn't compile. It is therefore unclear what needs to be done. One thing though stands out: The first thing you do in Compose with a view model's flow is to collect it. Do NOT pass it as a parameter. Something similar applies to State objects: Only pass their value to other composable functions. Please update the code in your question so it compiles and make sure the parameters are of the proper type.

I apologize for the uncompiled code; it was written merely as an example to illustrate the situation. I have now revised it for clarity. Please be aware that in the actual MyPassengerForm code, there are numerous fields, and some may be off-screen. Should any field contain an error, I will need to scroll to bring the first erroneous field into view.

I understand that directly passing state to a function is not ideal, but if I don't encapsulate the flow within the state, then 'MyPassengerForm' will become unskipable due to the unstable parameter being passed to the function.

Seeing the need to pass State or Flow objects to Composable functions is usually an indicator that something else is wrong. Compose is declarative and expects immutable state to be passed down and events to be passed up the compose tree.
In this case your view model should expose the needScroll like so:
private val _needScroll = MutableStateFlow(false)
val needScroll = _needScroll.asStateFlow()

Then your screen can collect it as usual and the Boolean value (not the flow, not the state) can be passed on to MyPassengerForm. Now, since everything is state-based, MyPassengerForm just needs to decide what to do when needScroll is true:
if (needScroll) LaunchedEffect(passengerState) {
    lifecycle.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
        val bringIntoView = when {
            passengerState.field1.isError -> field1BringIntoView
            passengerState.field2.isError -> field2BringIntoView
            else -> null
        }
        bringIntoView?.bringIntoView()
    }
}

Actually, executing the LaunchedEffect everytime passengerState is changed isn't necessary, you only need that if bringIntoView changes. So that should be moved outside the LaunchedEffect:
val bringIntoViewRequester = remember(needScroll, passengerState) {
    if (needScroll) when {
        passengerState.field1.isError -> field1BringIntoView
        passengerState.field2.isError -> field2BringIntoView
        else -> null
    } else
        null
}

if (bringIntoViewRequester != null) LaunchedEffect(bringIntoViewRequester) {
    lifecycle.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
        bringIntoViewRequester.bringIntoView()
    }
}

Although not thoroughly tested, I think you can even drop the repeatOnLifecycle.
Your view model's onSave method now just needs to set _needScroll.value = true instead of emitting a new value.
The interesting part is how that is reset to false. That depends entirely on what behavior you want. If you don't reset it, the LaunchedEffect will be executed everytime bringIntoViewRequester changes. That may be true when onSave is executed again and now another field has an error. When there are no errors left, bringIntoViewRequester is null so the LaunchedEffect is skipped alltogether. If this behavior is fine for you, you do not even need the needScroll variable and the correspondig flow, so that could be removed entirely.
If you have some other requirements, you can always expose an onScroll function in your view model that can be called from your composables when needScroll should be reset:
fun onScroll() {
    _needScroll.value = false
}

Some additional notes unrelated to your current problem:

You wrap your view model's functions in multiple lambdas and call remember. Instead, you should just pass a reference to the function to your composable:
MyPassengerForm(
    passengerState = passengerState,
    needScroll = needScroll,
    onChangeField1 = viewModel::onChangeField1,
    onChangeField2 = viewModel::onChangeField2,
    onSave = viewModel::onSave,
)


In your view model at some point you retrieve the _passengerState flow's current value and save it in cueState. At another point you update the flow's then current value and set an error state that is dependent on the older state of the flow. The problem is that the flow can be changed in between those two points. Every part of the flow that is needed to determine its new values should always be placed inside the update lambda, like this, for example:
_passengerState.update {
    var newState = it

    if (it.field1.value.isEmpty() || it.field2.value.isEmpty()) {
        newState = it.copy(
            field1 = it.field1.copy(isError = it.field1.value.isEmpty()),
            field2 = it.field2.copy(isError = it.field2.value.isEmpty()),
        )
        _needScroll.value = true
    }

    newState
}




Thank you for such a detailed answer. I can add that passing a function by reference does not ensure the stability of these parameters. You can read about it here: https://habr.com/ru/companies/ozontech/articles/742854/#2.4:~:text=viewModel%3A%3AonAction)%2C-,%D0%BD%D0%BE,-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D1%81%20Compose
The article is written in Russian, but there are English-language sources in the highlighted paragraph.

I'm not sure what point you're trying to make. Stability in Compose is easily achieved if you only pass immutable objects (as in my answer). The code from your question wasn't stable, because you passed a MutableState object. And if this wasn't bad enough, the content of that object was a Flow that also isn't stable and can change anytime. That's the reason for the first paragraph of my answer.
